How to swap and send
I manage to send raydium swap using typescript but i cant manage to swap and send the spl token to another address within the same transaction. Anyone here have tips on how to do it I tried transactions.add but theres a problem with my swap so I am wondering whether there is a simpler way to achieve this like a library via python perhaps?
